# How to downgrade user permissions on a java app after opening port 80/443

Tags: permissions, java, users, downgrade, application-development

I'm a Java developer writing a web app (Jetty server).

Are there any guides out there are how I might downgrade user permissions using Java?

Most native Linux apps will start as root, open root-only ports like 80/443, then downgrade themselves to a non root user (through a process which I'm not familiar with).

I'd like to be able to do the same in a Java environment.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-can-i-run-a-server-on-linux-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user

Comment: That's what I needed to see, thanks sergio91pt, can you post that as an answer so I can close this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ServerFault theres a similar [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-can-i-run-a-server-on-linux-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user) with a bunch of different solutions.